# Applying condition and update on same column

Tags: python, pandas

I have written the following statement to update a column in DataFrame (df)

```
    score
0   6800
1   7200
2   580
3   6730
```

df["score"] = (df["score"]/10).where(df["score"] > 999)

The idea is to clean up the score column to remove the extra '0' at the end, only if the number is greater than 999 else keep unchanged. However, i get the following result.

```
0    680.0
1    720.0
2      NaN
3    673.0
```

Also, I want the result as Integers.

my expected output

```
0    680
1    720
2    580
3    673
```

**Update**

the following worked for me

```
df["score"] = np.where(df["score"] > 999, df["score"]/10, df["score"]).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Do as in `numpy`, and use [masks](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

```
df['score'][df['score']>999] /= 10
```

For legibility you could do:

```
f = df['score']
f[f>999] /= 10
```

### Explanation

`df['score']>999` will create a mask, a `bool` array of the same shape as `df['score']` with `True`/`False` values at the positions of the values fulfilling/not fulfilling the given condition. E.g., in the example above:

```
In [27]: df['score']>999
Out[27]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: score, dtype: bool
```

You can use this mask to index the array/dataframe directly, to extract only matching elements:

```
In [28]: df['score'][df['score']>999]
Out[28]: 
0    6800
1    7200
3    6730
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

We divide all matching elements by ten and directly assign the result, using `/= 10`:

```
In [29]: df['score'][df['score']>999] /= 10

In [30]: df['score']
Out[30]: 
0    680
1    720
2    580
3    673
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `other` argument to the method [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
(df["score"]/10).where(df["score"] > 999, other=df["score"])
0    680.0
1    720.0
2    580.0
3    673.0
```

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me

df["score"] = np.where(df["score"] > 999, df["score"]/10, df["score"]).astype(int)